Ретрансляция HLS на Django сайт
АПИ видео оборудования позволяет в моменте запросить короткое видео в формате HLS, у меня задача настроить трансляцию этого видео на Django проекте. Ссылка от АПИ на трансляцию выглядит так:
https://ip:port/hls/tocken/master.m3u8

Пробовал запихнуть ссылку в видео и создать новый объект HLS:
video_pleer = document.createElement("video");
video_pleer.controls = "play";

var hls = new Hls();
hls.loadSource(href на трансляцию);
hls.attachMedia(video_pleer);
hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() { video_pleer.play(); });

Не вышло, возникает бесконечная загрузка и видео не подтягивается. Может у кого-то был опыт в реализации чего-то подобного и вы можете им поделиться, буду благодарен. Так же на сервере развернут чат использующий django-channels, возможно можно реализовать воспроизведение асинхронного потока используя его - в сети есть такие предположения, но вариантов реализации - не нашел.
